# Flawed Proof of Squeeze Theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I know that this "proof" is flawed, but I'm trying to understand exactly where the flaw lies.

Given: $s_n \leq x_n \leq t_n \forall N.$

If $\lim_{x\rightarrow{\infty}} s_n= \lim_{x\rightarrow{\infty}} t_n = L$ take the limit in the inequality $s_n \leq x_n \leq t_n$ to get that $L\leq \lim_{x\rightarrow{\infty}} x_n \leq L$, so $\lim_{x\rightarrow{\infty}} x_n = L.$

Is the problem that the $N(\epsilon)$ is different for the two seqences $s_n$ and $t_n,$ so we have to consider $\max(N_1(\epsilon), N_2(\epsilon)$? Or am I missing the point here?

Comment: I think the problem could be that you are presupposing that $x_n$ has a limit when you take that limit. Perhaps you should be invoking limit inferior on the left, and limit superior on the right?

Comment: Just to clarify, I do know how to prove the squeeze theorem correctly, I just want to understand why this one is _incorrect._

Comment: Right, but unless I'm blind, thats the only flaw I think I can find.

Comment: But don't we know that $x_n$ converges, because it is bound between two convergent sequences?

Comment: Well we will know when we finish the proof of the sequeeze theorem. Until then the only thing guaranteed to exist are the inferior and superior limits.

Comment: No, we don't know that $x_n$ converges because it is bounded between two convergent sequences. $(-1)^n$ is bounded between the constant sequence $1$ and the constant sequence $-1$ and it does not converge.

Comment: Aloizio, the point is that the two convergent sequences converge *to the same limit*.

Comment: @Valborg I know the point. Look at his argument on his second comment.

Comment: He is clearly referencing his stated problem, in which the sequences he mentions have the same limit.

Comment: @Valborg I disagree. Otherwise there would be no question at all. It is not clear that he knows his argument "(...) we know that $x_n$ converges, because it is bound between two convergent sequences?" is wrong, *as stated*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45896/discussion-between-valborg-and-aloizio-macedo).

Comment: I modified the question to clarify what I meant. So is the problem that we don't know that $x_n$ converges?

Comment: Correct, Mathematically. Until we have proven the Squeeze Theorem, we cannot use it to deduce that $x_n$ converges. So we instead invoke the inferior and superior limits. It adds at most 4 more inequalities to the mix.